# Update page hash on scroll performance problems

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm trying to update the page hash each time the user scrolls to a certain section:

```
<section data-anchor="projects"></section>

$(document).bind('scroll',function(e){
    $('section').each(function(){
      var element = $(this),
      dataHashValue = element.data('anchor');

      if(dataHashValue) {
        var sectionOffset = 10,
        elementOffsetTop = element.offset().top,
        elementHeight = element.height(),
        currentPageOffsetY = window.pageYOffset;

        if (elementOffsetTop < currentPageOffsetY + sectionOffset
          && elementOffsetTop + elementHeight > currentPageOffsetY + sectionOffset) {
          window.location.hash = dataHashValue;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

My problem with this is that I'm having performance issues, the framerate drops a lot when the user is scrolling fast... How can I optimize this code? (I tried the history API but that makes it a lot worse).

EDIT: following Taytorious advice I implemented a Debouncer, however the loop within the update function is still dropping my framerate a lot

```
function AutoHash() {
    this.scroller = window;
    this.elements = $('[data-anchor]').map(function(index, item) {
      var $element = $(item);

      return {
        yOffset: $element.offset().top,
        height: $element.height(),
        dataHashValue: $element.data('anchor')
      };
    });
  }

update : function (lastScroll, currentScroll) {
      this.elements.each(function(index, item) {
          var sectionOffset = 10,
          currentPageOffsetY = currentScroll;

          if (item.yOffset < currentPageOffsetY + sectionOffset
            && item.yOffset + item.height > currentPageOffsetY + sectionOffset) {
            window.location.hash = item.dataHashValue;
          }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the browser is firing that scroll event several times per second (it varies from browser to browser). You are iterating through a loop and manipulating the DOM, and those are costly operations to execute in quick succession. You can get around this with a scroll debouncer and a little bit of code refactor. For the scroll debouncer:

```
function scrollDebounce(context, callback) {
    var latestKnownScrollY = 0,
        lastScroll = 0;
    ticking = false;

    function onScroll() {
        latestKnownScrollY = window.scrollY;
        requestTick();
    }

    function requestTick() {
        if(!ticking) {
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }
        ticking = true;
    }

    function update() {
        // reset the tick so we can
        // capture the next onScroll
        ticking = false;


        var currentScrollY = latestKnownScrollY;

        callback.apply(context, [lastScroll, currentScrollY]);

        lastScroll = currentScrollY;
    }


    $(window).scroll(onScroll);
}
```

This will execute the callback only when the browser is requesting a new frame. For the callback, you're probably not going to want to loop through all your sections every time. I'd store the offset positions of all the sections in some sort of data structure and keep track of the current section. That way you can easily iterate to the next/previous section depending on whether the user is scrolling up or down.

```
this.currentIndex = 0;

function AutoHash() {
    this.scroller = window;
    this.elements = $('[data-anchor]').map(function(index, item) {
        var $element = $(item);

        return {
            top: $element.offset().top,
            bottom: $element.offset().top + $element.height(),
            dataHashValue: $element.data('anchor')
        };
    });
}

update : function (lastScroll, currentScroll) {

    if (lastScroll < currentScroll && this.elements[this.currentIndex + 1].top < currentScroll) {

        this.currentIndex++;

    } else if (lastScroll > currentScroll && this.elements[this.currentIndex - 1].bottom > currentScroll && this.currentIndex > 0) {

        this.currentIndex--;

    }

    window.location.hash = this.elements[this.currentIndex].dataHashValue;

}

scrollDebounce(this, this.update);
```

Comment: This is nice, and it helps, but there's still a lot of overhead; I stored the offsets in an array, but I can't think on a way of keeping track of the current section without having to iterate through the array on each update, I think the main issue is that loop, can you maybe elaborate on this?

Comment: Something like this should work. If you're looking for something cleaner/easier, look into [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a smart scroll like this :)

```
var smartScroll;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout(smartScroll);
    smartScroll = setTimeout(doneScrolling, 100);
});

function doneScrolling(){
    console.log('Your performance scrollcode here');
}
```

What it does is that it runs 100ms after the scrolling stops. You can even lower the ms to what you see fit for the performance. Maybe 20ms will also do.

To be more precise it kills the donescrolling function if the user keeps scrolling within that ms limit. But it will not kill the last set timeout call for the done scrolling function when the user stops scrolling.

Peace and love!